# To draw a pie chart in excel using winnovative

Tags: c#, excel, winnovative

I am using `Winnovative` to write data to an excel sheet from my C# code. Writing data from a data table works fine without any issues. I intend to have a pie chart from the data I have written. So I have a template of the excel sheet where I have predrawn a pie chart for 3 columns and am trying to insert values there using my code instead of drawing the pie chart in code which is [possible.](http://www.winnovative-software.com/ExcelLibDemo/ChartsDemo.aspx)

However when I try to open the excel file I get an error "Another process is using the excel file". So is the pie chart creation considered as a process running? Is there a way where I can define cells for the chart and define values to it from my code uysing `Winnovative`? Is there a way I can hold off the processing of the chart until the values from the code are passed?

This is my code where I am getting the exception.

```
string dataFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), @"Data\awemployees.xls");
System.IO.FileStream sourceXlsDataStream = new System.IO.FileStream(dataFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

ExcelWorkbook tempWorkbook = new ExcelWorkbook(sourceXlsDataStream);//Error
```